# function inside a loop - powershell

Tags: powershell

How do I call a function inside loop? I'm trying to run an infinite loop that will run a function(s). I have something like this

```
#Infinite loop to filter file
while ($true){
    #run this function
    filterFile
}


function filterFile{
   #do filtering of files here
}

function anotherFunction{
    #another function 
}
```

If it possible how can I achieve it, if not is there other way?

Comment: Move your functions to before the loop, and you should be just fine.

Comment: That works great. I think i was overthinking too much and forgot to do this. Thankss!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the "TheMadTechnician's" answer. Changing the order will do that:

```
function filterFile{
   #do filtering of files here
}

#Infinite loop to filter file
while ($true){
    #run this function
    filterFile
}
```